Displays a list of range names for a worksheet on another worksheet
In a workbook there are 2 worksheets, Detail and Group. In the Group sheet there are 3 ranges, "mk_1", "mk_2", and "mk_3" with worksheet scope.
How can I display listnames of the three ranges on the Group sheet in the Details sheet in Excel VBA.
Range(Selection.Address).Select
Selection.ListNames

Doesn't show anything
Expected results:
mk_1
mk_2
mk_3


This code scans and prints the named ranges names into column A on the target sheet.
The Names method is iterated through the Name objects of the sheet.
Sub to_name()
Set sh = Worksheets("Group")   'source sheet with named ranges
Set tsh = Worksheets("Detail")  'target sheet

For i = 1 To sh.Names.Count
  tsh.Cells(i, "A") = sh.Names(i).Name
  tsh.Cells(i, "B") = "'" & sh.Names(i).RefersTo
Next i
End Sub




great answer, sir.
